# Create a function that returns a list of factors after after applying function for each value of a vector in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a vector of prediction probabilities and I want to classify the vector for each value in a prediction threshold vector. So that the first element of the list will be a factor classified when threshold is equal to 0 and the last element of the list will be a factor when threshold equals 1. My attempt is below any help is appreciated.

```
set.seed(1)
Predictions=runif(100)
predClassify=function(x){

 Classifier=function(x,y){ifelse(x>=y,"Over","Under")}
  classThreshold=seq(0,1,.1)
  tmp=list()
  for(i in seq_along(classThreshold)){
    tmp[[?]]=as.factor(myClassifierFunc(x,classThreshold[i]))# not sure how to index this an outer for loop?
    return(tmp)
  }

classifiedList=predClassify(Predictions)
```

Comment: It would be `tmp[[i]]` if you have `tmp <- vector('list', length(classThreshold))`

Comment: @akrun there must be something else wrong with my code after making the changes you suggested only the first element of the list is populated the rest are NULL's

Comment: You need to return `tmp` outside the `for` loop

Comment: I updated the post with the full function.  Please check

Comment: @akrun Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an empty `list`, create a `NULL` `list` of `length` equal to the `length` of 'classThreshold' and then do the assignment with `tmp[[i]]`

```
tmp <- vector('list', length(classThreshold))
for(i in seq_along(classThreshold)){
    tmp[[i]]=as.factor(myClassifierFunc(x,classThreshold[i]))
}
```

---

Using the full function

```
predClassify=function(x){

    Classifier <- function(x,y){ifelse(x >= y, "Over", "Under")}
    classThreshold <- seq(0,1,.1)
    tmp <- vector('list', length(classThreshold))
    for(i in seq_along(classThreshold)){
       tmp[[i]]=as.factor(Classifier(x,classThreshold[i]))

      }
     tmp
   }
```

-checking

```
classifiedList <- predClassify(Predictions)
lengths(classifiedList)
#[1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```